# How to develop/test a Google Script app that is not verified

Tags: google-apps-script

Recently Google announced [OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)

I don't get it. Before verifying an app with Google, I have to develop one, right? But how do I test it, if I don't have the option to run it for myself as a developer without any verification restriction.

For example, I'm developing an app that uses Drive. I need access to Drive at least for myself. Or am I missing something. 
Anybody, please help!

Comment: Check the configuration of your google cloud project. You should have some credentials and you can use your app on your own account during development

Comment: Ok. One thing I didn't notice is that actually the verification warning screen allows you to proceed at your own risk. This gives a developer an opportunity to test.